# O que falta neste código?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val minhaTarefa = Tarefa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro")

    minhaTarefa.entregar()
}
   class TarefaDeCasa(
     var nomeDoAluno: String,
     var nomeDaMateria: String,
     var nota: Int,
       var dataDeEntrega: String) {

   fun entregar() {
        println("o aluno ${nomeDoAluno} entregou a tarefa do dia ${dataDeEntrega} e recebeu a nota ${nota}")
        }
  }
```

> source.kt:4:23: error: unresolved reference: Tarefa val minhaTarefa = Tarefa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro") ^

Comment: Boa pergunta, pode nos informar porque acha que falta alguma coisa?

Comment: Por favor, reformule a pergunta para sabermos qual a sua dúvida.

Comment: Aparece o seguinte erro:
source.kt:4:23: error: unresolved reference: Tarefa
    val minhaTarefa = Tarefa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro")
                      ^

Comment: Mas não sei o que preciso fazer para resolver, vocês podem me ajudar?

Comment: Aparentemente não existe uma classe chamada `Tarefa`.

Comment: O nome da classe está errado, tenta como `val minhaTarefa = TarefaDeCasa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro")`

Comment: Era Exatamente isso!!! muito obrigado pessoal! consegui fazer o código!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma classe chamada **`Tarefa`**, o nome da classe é **`TarefaDeCasa`**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val minhaTarefa = TarefaDeCasa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro")

    minhaTarefa.entregar()
}

class TarefaDeCasa(
    var nomeDoAluno: String,
    var nomeDaMateria: String,
    var nota: Int,
    var dataDeEntrega: String) {

    fun entregar() {
        println("o aluno ${nomeDoAluno} entregou a tarefa do dia ${dataDeEntrega} e recebeu a nota ${nota}")
    }
}
```

<sup>**Veja funcionando em** [**try.kotlinlang.org**](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/h6ej49bqrub7ct5304mdp467ee/5c55i4au5dlko2en04d2026vui)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Assim funciona, acho que era só erro de digitação já que a classe criada chama `TarefaDeCasa` e a chamada para instanciar estava `Tarefa`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val minhaTarefa = TarefaDeCasa("Daniel", "Programação", 10, "30 de Setembro")
    minhaTarefa.entregar()
}
class TarefaDeCasa(
    var nomeDoAluno: String,
    var nomeDaMateria: String,
    var nota: Int,
    var dataDeEntrega: String) {

    fun entregar() {
        println("o aluno ${nomeDoAluno} entregou a tarefa do dia ${dataDeEntrega} e recebeu a nota ${nota}")
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I6lZpC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ghgsdwrn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/InstanceObject.kt).